# d3 bar chart with range selector in x-axis (like dygraphs)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart, dygraphs

Is it possible to generate a bar chart in d3 and use similar tool or feature like the one in dygraphs ([this](http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/range-selector)) for range Selector? I want to zoom in and out for the time on x-axis.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367)?

Comment: rickshaw charts are based on d3 and provide the range selector, you may want to give it a try.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use `d3.brush` to create this functionality. Here is an example from the creator of d3 on how to use it - and it is exactly what you wanted (zoomable bar-chart): http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367